# Rewriting a url using rewrite in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I have an requirement were I have to re-route a call to
https://www.myweb/order to
https://www.testweb/product

writing something like this in nginx.config is not working-

```
     location ~* /order {
     rewrite /order/(.*) /product/(.*) last;
     proxy_pass {{env "TEST"}};
     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
     }
```

Here "TEST" has been set as "https://www.testweb"

But this is throwing 404 .

Answer (score 0):

Your `rewrite` is incorrect in two places. The second expression should use `$1` to represent the value of the capture `(.*)` in the first expression.

Also, use `break` instead of `last` to keep processing the rewritten URL within the same `location` block. See [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) documentation.

For example:

```
location ^~ /order {
    rewrite ^/order/(.*)$ /product/$1 break;
    ...
}
```

I have also changed the *regular expression* location block into a *prefix* location. See [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) documentation.